# How to reduce vertical space between two rSubsection in Latex

Tags: latex, overleaf

I am trying to create my resume in overleaf/latex but I am not able to reduce the space between two rSubsection inside my rSection. I am using overleaf.com to do it. Please find the code below

```latex
\begin{rSection}{Education}
\begin{rSubsection}{Netaji Subhas Institute of Technology, Delhi University}{New Delhi, India}{B.E in Mechanical Engineering, CGPA: 8.7}{2015-2019}
%\vspace{-.1cm}
%Overall GPA: 78\%
\vspace{-.65cm}
\item[]
\end{rSubsection}
\begin{rSubsection}{Kendriya Vidyalaya Muradnagar, CBSE}{Ghaziabad, UP}{Higher Senior Secondary, Aggregate 94\%}{2013-2014}
%\vspace{-.1cm}
%Overall GPA: 78\%
\vspace{-.65cm}
\item[]
\end{rSubsection}
\begin{rSubsection}{Kendriya Vidyalaya Muradnagar, CBSE}{Ghaziabad, UP}{Senior Secondary, CGPA 10.0}{2011-2012}
%\vspace{-.1cm}
%Overall GPA: 78\%
\vspace{-.65cm}
\item[]
\end{rSubsection}
\end{rSection}
```

and output is
[image]

I want to reduce the space marked in red.
Please help me here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre] and also link to the template you use

Answer (score -1):

Try using \vspace{-5pt}, \vspace{-10pt} etc.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).